# Child component won't update with new props after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the google-map-react module, passing in center coordinates that I would like to have updated after an API call. They are being passed in as props, from state of the parent component. However, when I update the state in the parent component, the child component () doesn't update, and I also see the following warning in my console: `GoogleMap: defaultCenter prop changed. You can't change default props.`

I was expecting the child to re-render, but that isn't happening. Any thoughts?

```
const React = require('react')
const GoogleMap = require('google-map-react').default

const MapPage = React.createClass({
  propTypes () {
    return ({
      params: object
    })
  },
  getInitialState () {
    return ({
      zipSearch: this.props.params.zip || '90024',
      initialCoordinates: [59.955413, 30.337844]
    })
  },
  componentWillMount () {
    $.get('www.APICALL.com', function (result)     {
      var resources = JSON.parse(result);
      this.setState({
        initialCoordinates: [parseFloat(resources[0].latitude), parseFloat(resources[0].longitude)]
      })
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render () {
    var initialCoordinates = {lat: this.state.initialCoordinates[0], lng: this.state.initialCoordinates[1]}
    console.log(initialCoordinates) //this gets logged twice in console.log
    return (
      <div className='map-container'>
         <GoogleMap
          defaultCenter={initialCoordinates}
          defaultZoom={12}>
        </GoogleMap>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

module.exports = MapPage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says exactly what's wrong, you can't change the defaults. Set `defaultCenter` once, then use your dynamic state variable on `center`. Same thing with `defaultZoom` and `zoom` in case you need to change that.

Comment: That was a very boneheaded mistake of mine..I kept thinking it was an issue with react not allowing me to change passed in props to child components. Sorry, new entrant to react here. I'll learn to read the docs better.. Thanks a lot!!